# writing facebook app new SDK with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook

Is there any new SDK compatible with new facebook api fod .net developers ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to take a look at the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/), which is now on [github](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/) too. I've not used it myself, but the latest commit was a couple of days ago, which is promising.

I have previously used the [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/), but support has since been discontinued.

Comment: @gruber - Your question is not marked as wanting to know about javascript.  The normal Facebook SDK published by Facebook should work with javascript.

Comment: are there any limitations using javascript api despite of server side api ?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid, but I was under the impression that their js API is fairly fully featured. You can dig into more detail on facebook's official js API documentation here: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript